# WordPress Get Terms and Posts Query is Breaking Other Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have the following query, which is designed to show a list of terms in a taxonomy, and under each term, a list of posts assigned to that term.

This appears in a sidebar on the left hand side of my single.php posts page.  In the main area of the page, the actual single post is meant to display.

However, instead of displaying the current single post, it is only displaying the TITLE for the most recent single post.

Here is my query:

```
$terms = get_terms('benefit-cats');
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'benefit-cats','term'=>$term->slug);
        $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        echo "<li class=\"list-item\">".$term->name.""; //<a href=\"".get_term_link($term->slug, 'benefit-cats')."\"></a>//
        echo "<ul class=\"children\">";
        $posts = $query->posts;
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
        }       
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

I have tried adding reset query to the code, to no avail.  I have identified that it is this specific section that is causing the problem:

```
$posts = $query->posts;
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
            }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?  I have been trouble shooting this for 30-40 minutes now without any success.

Would appreciate an explanation of my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
<?php
if ($query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".the_title()."</a></li>";
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

in place of

```
$posts = $query->posts;
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
            }
```

hope this will work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments for `WP_Query` aren't well formed.

Here's how it should be for taxonomy (snippet taken from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) ):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bob'
        )
    )
);
```

After you get your arguments right, you should [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) over the results:

```
while( $query->have_posts() ):
  $query->the_post();
  // It is now that get_permalink() will work
endwhile;
```